# "Progressively" loading entities from RESTful API in NgRx

Tags: angular, rest, api, redux, ngrx

I'm building an application using Angular 7 and NgRx, and trying this with the Entity State Adapter.

I want to ask for one or more objects from NgRx by ID, but if it's not in the store, I want to ask for it from the RESTful API, then put it in the NgRx store.

I built the RESTful API and can ask for any number of objects with an array of IDs, and I read about how I can select objects from NgRx using one or more IDs, and I know how to load data into NgRx using effects and reducers.

But, how can I get the system to work so that if I ask for one or more objects by ID, it will return the existing ones from the store if they exist and/or update the store by requesting them from the RESTful API.

There's a lot of data so pre-loading it all is inefficient, but there are mixed uses where I'll need to show a list of many, or show a single one, or show related objects by ID, etc.

For example:

List page wants IDs 0-10 to show in a list. Ask the store for them, store doesn't have them, so it gets them from the API. Now the store has 0-10 and the list displays them.

Details page wants ID 10, the store has it from previous loading the list page (in this case), but it also wants ID 13 and 14 because they're related, so I'm going to ask for 10, 13, and 14. The store has 10 so it displays immediately, but has to request 13 and 14 from the RESTful API and populates the store when they return.

List page shows "page 2", which is IDs 11-20, and 13 and 14 are already in the store, so it just has to go get 11-12 and 15-20 from the API, etc.

Multiplied by thousands, because there's too much data to just load locally all at once.

My bad solution:

My thought about achieving this is have a selector for id[], and that selector returns whichever IDs already exist in the store, and then dispatches an action for the missing IDs so then the effects and reducers do their job. I don't know how to get a selector to dispatch an action (if that's even the right approach).

Alternately, in the component asking for the data, it dispatches the action for whatever data doesn't come back from the selector, but putting that logic in the component isn't a good place for it.

I thought about putting it in a service, which seems rational, but I'm not sure how then to communicate the store/state to the component and the service without having to duplicate a bunch of code, and/or how to pass state updates through the service to the component, and other weird realtime state issues.

Answer (score 2):

You could return the missing ID's from the selector (instead of list of found id's return an object containing a list of found entities and array of missing id's if any), and then in the subscription (or tap if you utilise $async pipe) dispatch the action which will fetch the missing id's via Effect.

Something like this:

```
export const $mySelector = createSelector($someEntitySelector, (entities, props: { ids: string[] }) => {
  const items = [];
  const missingIds = [];

  props.ids.map(id => {
    if (entities[id]) {
       items.push(entities[id]);
    } else {
       missingIds.push(id);
    }

  })

  return {
    items,
    missingIds
  }
});
```

in the component:

```
  this.store$.select($mySelector).pipe(
    tap({items, missingIds} => {
       if (missingIds) {
         // dispatch action that will trigger the effect
       }
    })

  )
```

You would definitely need to handle a case where there is no ID on the server (if the service doesn't find it safest bet is to delete that id so it doesn't call the service again for no reason)

Comment: I ended up just removing ngrx because it was just too hard and complicated to implement and I couldn't even begin to figure out how to do what I wanted. Seems to be par for the course with Angular.

Comment: There is a crash course on that from Angular University though: https://blog.angular-university.io/ngrx-entity/